# Measures on sites

Tags: ct.category-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category equipped with a Grothendieck topology $\tau$, i.e., a site.

Under which conditions on $\mathcal{C}$ can one construct a Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $\sigma_\tau$, for $\tau$?

If one *can* construct $\sigma_\tau$, can one then sensibly define a "finitely additive measure" $\mu$ on $\mathcal{C}$ for $\sigma_\tau$ that takes values in an additive category $\mathcal{A}$?

Which additional conditions on $\mathcal{A}$ would ensure that such a *categorical measure*, if one is possible, behaves like the usual $\sigma$-additive measures?

Comment: I don't think so (certainly not in the generality where the measure takes values in an additive category), but @UrsSchreiber might know?

Comment: A site abstracts from the notion of topological space the fact that there is a collection of open sets, and that we know what it means for one collection to cover another. This isn't nearly enough information to imitate the construction of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. You'd have a better shot looking at the topos of sheaves on $\mathcal C$, since there are good notions of open and closed subtoposes, but I don't know of anything suggesting this leads in a useful direction.

Comment: You might be interested in the theory of [the symmetric topos](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+topos), which I think is supposed to give a notion of measure or distribution on a topos. Of the top of my head, if $E$ is a topos and $A$ is a cocomplete abelian category, I would think about functors $E \to A$ which preserve the initial object, preserve pushouts (in analogy to the principle of inclusion-exclusion), and preserve filtered colimits (the $\sigma$ part of $\sigma$ additivity) -- all told, functors preserving all colimits.

Comment: You might also be interested in the [PhD thesis by Matthew Jackson](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/students/jackson.pdf). He develops the foundation of what could be called synthetic measure theory by exploiting that, from the internal point of view of a suitable topos, the sheaf of measurable functions looks like the plain old set of Dedekind real numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that a good reference might be Olivier Leroy's theory, developing measure theory for locales (a special kind of topoi). Unfortunately Leroy passed away dramatically in 1996 and the paper has been typeset by Claire Voisin and Jean Malgoire, and can be dowloaded from [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.5631). The paper is in French and the title can roughly be translated as "Measure theory in locales or: hidden intersections in Banach-Tarsky's paradox" (the original title is *Théorie de la mesure dans les lieux réguliers ou : Les intersections cachées dans le paradoxe de Banach-Tarski*).